# Issue with loading file from URL, only where located in certain places

Tags: r, dropbox, openxlsx

I have an issue with loading data from a Dropbox folder, and have absolutely no idea why. [Several posts suggest that the issue can be solved by closing the file before loading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543934/import-excel-data-into-r-using-openxlsx-error-in-filecon-r-invalid-desc), but it's obviously not it in my case: it works when the file is located in my personal Dropbox, but fails when the exact same file is located in my pro Dropbox...

```
library("openxlsx")
works <- read.xlsx("
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9lcwo7pj334oo83mraz5a/IOTC-DATASETS-2024-01-29-SF-SKJ-1982-2022.xlsx?rlkey=s8vhjrayk3tw1tju3jgw29g90&dl=1", sheet = "DATA")
fails <- read.xlsx("
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/qwsdkl1cwjmmoq14grb6u/IOTC-DATASETS-2024-01-29-SF-SKJ-1982-2022.xlsx?rlkey=8ufrizdorbxoyreaslhgjhuu0&dl=1", sheet = "DATA")
```

Error says:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
6.
file(con, "r")
5.
readLines(x, warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
4.
readUTF8(workbookRelsXML)
3.
paste(readUTF8(workbookRelsXML), collapse = "")
2.
read.xlsx.default("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7x3vj88zkbahkkfrfszj1/IOTC-DATASETS-2024-01-29-SF-SKJ-1982-2022.xlsx?rlkey=8h13zak9nkj9c2z6p8vyx3tm6&dl=1",
sheet = "DATA")
1.
read.xlsx("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7x3vj88zkbahkkfrfszj1/IOTC-DATASETS-2024-01-29-SF-SKJ-1982-2022.xlsx?rlkey=8h13zak9nkj9c2z6p8vyx3tm6&dl=1",
sheet = "DATA")
```

Any idea why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The download link of the second does not work for me. Might explain your issue?

Comment: Yes, as Jan said, it looks like the permissions on the second link don't actually allow public access. The permissions would need to be changed to allow that.